# Как остановит выполнение программы?

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы если значение, которое будет написано к первому инпут 
будет `не` "**`да`**", а что-то другое, тогда код перестал работать?

main.py

```
start = input("""
Привет, ты решил подать заявку на работу? 
(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):
""") 

if start == "да": 
    print("""
        Хорошо, ты должен будешь пройти мини-тест, чтоб понять, 
        подходишь ты нам, или нет: 
    """) 
else: 
    print("Спасибо за внимание!") 
    
one_question = input("""
    1)Знаешь ли ты языки Python, HTML, CSS, JS и SQL 
    (если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):
""")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: я пишу программу типо анкеты, если посмотреть на фото, то можно понять, что если ввести значение "да", то тогда выходит сообщение "Хорошо, ты должен будешь пройти мини-тест.....", а если ввести другое значение. например "нет", то выходит сообщение "спасибо за внимание", мне надо что бы при введение любого значения, кроме "да", выводилось сообщение "спасибо за внимание" и код дальше перестал компилироваться

Comment: приведите ваш код обычным текстом

Comment: start = input("Привет, ты решил подать заявку на работу?(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):")

if start == "да":
    print("Хорошо, ты должен будешь пройти мини-тест, чтоб понять, подходишь ты нам, или нет:  ")
else:
    print("Спасибо за внимание!")
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
one_question = input("1)Знаешь ли ты языки Python, HTML, CSS, JS и SQL(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):")

Comment: Что значит "перестал работать"? Это можно по-разному сделать

Answer (score 1):

1

```
start = input("Привет, ты решил подать заявку на работу?(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):")
if start == "да":
    print("Хорошо, ты должен будешь пройти мини-тест, чтоб понять, подходишь ты нам, или нет: ")
    one_question = input("1)Знаешь ли ты языки Python, HTML, CSS, JS и SQL(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):")
    # тест
else:
    print("Спасибо за внимание!")
```

2

```
start = input("Привет, ты решил подать заявку на работу?(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):")
if start == "да":
    print("Хорошо, ты должен будешь пройти мини-тест, чтоб понять, подходишь ты нам, или нет: ")
else:
    print("Спасибо за внимание!")
    exit()
one_question = input("1)Знаешь ли ты языки Python, HTML, CSS, JS и SQL(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):")
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я поняла, под "перестала работать" вы имеете ввиду, что весь код, написанный ниже конструкции input(), не должен выполняться от слова вообще. В этом может помочь инструкция [assert](https://pythonru.com/uroki/35-instrukcija-assert-dlja-nachinajushhih)

В вашем случае, код будет выглядеть так:

```
start = input("""
Привет, ты решил подать заявку на работу? 
(если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):
""") 

assert start == "да" # вот что нужно вам

if start == "да": 
    print("""
        Хорошо, ты должен будешь пройти мини-тест, чтоб понять, 
        подходишь ты нам, или нет: 
    """) 
else: 
    print("Спасибо за внимание!") 

one_question = input("""
    1)Знаешь ли ты языки Python, HTML, CSS, JS и SQL 
    (если да, то напиши да, если нет, то пиши что хочешь):
""")
```

Далее можете править код как вам угодно)